# Linear Algebra, Full Rank and Invertibility

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $A^TA$ = \begin{pmatrix}
 3&  4&  0\\
 4&  10&  -3\\
 0&  -3& 
3\end{pmatrix}

(a) Solve the homogeneous system $Ax = 0$. Explain how you derive your
answer.

(b) Suppose $(A^T A)^{−1}A^T$ = \begin{pmatrix}
 \frac{3}{5}&  \frac{-4}{5}&  0&  \frac{3}{5}&  \frac{1}{5}\\
 \frac{-1}{5}&  \frac{3}{5}&  0&  \frac{-1}{5}&  \frac{-2}{5}\\
 \frac{-1}{5}&  \frac{4}{15}&  0&  \frac{-8}{15}& 
\frac{-11}{15}\end{pmatrix}What is A? Explain how you derive your answer.

(c) Find all possible left inverse of A.

I have found $A$ after doing $(A^TA)(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$ and got $A$ as\begin{bmatrix}
 1&  1&  0\\
 0&  2&  -1\\
 0&  0&  0\\
 1&  2&  -1\\
 -1&  -1& 
-1\end{bmatrix}
I am not sure if my method if correct but I know the RREF of A results in 3 pivot columns = rank 3 and given $A$ is a 5 x 3 matrix it is of full rank. Therefore the resulting identity matrix would be an 3 x 3 one. $A^{-1}A$ = $I_3$

So I tried to compute using this method \begin{bmatrix}
 a&  b&  c&  d&  e\\
 f&  g&  h&  i&  j\\
 k&  l&  m&  n& 
o\end{bmatrix}  where the first row multiply by the 3 columns of A should result in \begin{bmatrix}
 1&  0& 
0\end{bmatrix} as it is the first row of $I_3$

Will solving this three equations of linear systems mainly $a + d - e = 1, 
a + 2b +2d - e = 0 
-b -d -e = 0$ give me the possible parameters for the first row of $A^{-1}$ inverse. Then I continue this for the second and third row of the possible $A^{-1}$ inverse matrix until i get all 15 elements.

Comment: Please only ask only one question at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a)$ if $Ax=0$ then $A^T(Ax)=A^T0=0$ so $x$ is also a solution of the linear system $(A^TA)x=0$. By the way, your $A^TA$ is an invertibile matrix, so the only solution is $x=0$;

$b)$ what you wrote is right, just use

$$A^T=(A^TA)(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$$

And then you get $A$ as $A=(A^T)^T$.

$c)$ Your method is correct, but maybe not the faster one. I would like also to observe that you already have at least one left inverse of $A$, which is $BA^T$. Here $B$ is the inverse matrix of $A^TA$.